# Four partitions on MBR disk

Tags: windows-10, uefi, mbr, gpt

I have four partitions on an MBR disk:

1. Boot
2. Win 10 OS
3. File Storage
4. WinRE

I have a need to install Windows 10 on the third [File Storage] partition, but I have an error that states Windows on UEFI system can only be installed on GPT disk.

- I know I can convert disk to GPT with `diskpart`, where data is wiped out, or use EaseUS software, where I do not see an option to convert MBR to GPT
- Within the UEFI firmware settings [Lenovo Z51], I do not see an option to disable EFI boot

Any Ideas how to install Win 10 on an MBR disk?

- Partitioning schema: 
   [image: Screenshot]

SOLVED: I made a bootable USB using legacy-boot the installer using Rufus. Now I have two bootable partitions on MBR disk.

Comment: Could you please provide the disk partitions schema in the Windows 10 (in the disk manager) ? `MBR` disks can only have 4 physical partitions, if Windows create itself others partitions, it may be a problem.

Comment: It has 4 partitions

Comment: If you want to install Windows to MBR-partitioned disks, you must legacy-boot _the installer_.

Comment: How have you installed your current Windows 10 to MBR? Have you set the BIOS/UEFI to Legacy boot? Note that you can [Free Convert MBR to GPT Without Data Loss](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/will-converting-mbr-to-gpt-erase-all-the-disk-partitions.html) using [MiniTool Partition Wizard Free](https://www.minitool.com/partition-manager/partition-wizard-home.html). Except that we need to verify that this will not cause problems with the existing Windows 10 installation.

Comment: You can't have another Windows with a MBR disk as you already have 4 partitions. You need to convert in UEFI / GPT.

Comment: To convert a live system to GPT, use [`Mbr2Gpt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt). _No machine should be configured with [CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#CSM_booting) enabled_, as its sole purpose was to support distros that didn't yet support EFI boot circa <2017. Once the drive is converted to GPT, upon rebooting, disable CSM [Legacy] Mode within the UEFI firmware settings.

Comment: The authors disk doesn’t meet the requirements for MbR2GPT. They would need to delete the “New Volume” to meet the requirements. MBR2GPT is also a Windows 10 only tool. It would be easier to just expand the existing Windows installation using the free space.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question ! If you do that I'll upvote both question and answer.

Comment: @Marin Legacy boot is not meant to be used and is a really bad solution because performance is lost when CSM [legacy] Mode is enabled - it was never intended for Windows since Windows has supported EFI boot since Windows 7. UEFI is a 64bit firmware, BIOS is a 16bit firmware, and what CSM Mode does is emulate BIOS within a 32bit environment, of which causes boot times to be 45s+ versus ~10s with EFI boot, the OS is locked to four partitions since Windows requires MBR with CSM Mode enabled, versus GPT with EFI boot having no such restriction, etc. **Your system is incorrectly configured**